# Is it possible to create an ISM policy in Opensearch to delete documents in an index that are 30 days old

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, ism

I have an Opensearch index which keeps growing and incuring more cost. Is it possible to create ISM policies to delete the documents that are certain number of days old e.g. 30 days.

The ISM I tried only deletes the index instead of documents in the index